# X/Y cursor naming convention

Tags: oscilloscope

If I have an oscilloscope, and tell you to move the X cursor, does this cursor move horizontally (Read X values), or is the cursor itself horizontal, parallel to the X axis?

I need the correct naming for an API interfacing with an oscilloscope-like GUI widget, and to avoid confusion, I need the right name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keysight Oscilloscopes employee here - the "X" cursors are for measuring/displaying x-axis values and therefore must be drawn vertically.

Answer (score 3):

The X cursor reads X values. The cursor itself is displayed as a vertical line.